# IF ElseIF statements in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to write a script for a country-based Database search. The search is ran on a sheet full of data called "Database" and the results pasted to a different sheet called "Results".

The search is dependent on user-inputted variables, which I have defined as "Country", "Category" and "Subcategory":

```
country = Sheets("Results").Range("D5").Value
Category = Sheets("Results").Range("D6").Value
Subcategory = Sheets("Results").Range("D7").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Database").Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row
```

I want the search criteria filled in by the user through a `UserForm` to lead to different scenarios. As such:

1 - If the user  searches for a country that is not included in the database, the search will not run and a message saying so will pop up. I used a `.Find` function to so:

```
With Worksheets("Database")
        Set c = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=country, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Else
            MsgBox "Unfortunately, the database does not have any sources for information in " & country & ". Please search for sources in relating to another country."
            Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
            Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
            Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
```

2- If the user does not produce a name of a country to search for, the search will not run. I used an `IF` statement to do so:

```
If country = "" Then
        Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J200000").Clear
        MsgBox "You must select a country in order to search the database. Please do so in the drop-down list provided."
        Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

3 - If the user searches for a country in the database, the search runs, either listing all matches for the country or, if the user has narrowed the search by providing "Category" and "Subategory", listing only those database entries which match the three criteria. I have done this through an `IF` statement, separate from the first one:

```
For i = 2 To finalrow

    'If the country field is filled in and there results from the search made
    If Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = country And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 3) = Category Or Category = "") And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 4) = Subcategory Or Subcategory = "") Then

            'Copy the headers of the "Database" sheet
            With Sheets("Database")
            .Range("A1:I1").Copy
            End With
            Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J10").PasteSpecial

            'Copy the rows of the "Database" that match the search query
            With Sheets("Database")
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 9)).Copy
            End With
            Sheets("Results").Range("B20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
```

4 - As a last scenario, I want the script to react to the event where the user provides a "Country", a "Category" and/or a "Subcategory" but, although the database has entries for that country, it does not have entries for that country in that category or subcategory. In this case, I want the script to ask the user if it wants to see all information on the searched country, regardless of "Category" or "Subategory". I tried to do this through an `IfElse` statement, part of the previous `IF` statement:

```
ElseIf Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = country And _
       (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 3) <> Category) Then
        Dim question As Integer
        question = MsgBox("Unfortunately, the Database has no sources regarding " & Category & " in " & country & ". Would you perhaps want to broaden your search and see all sources regarding " & country & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "No results for your search")
        Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
        MsgBox question
            If question = vbYes Then
              Close
              Call SearchButton_Click
              Exit Sub
            Else
              Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
              Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
              Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
              Exit Sub
            End If
```

These are the four scenarios I want the script to account for as possible.

The search and the script as a whole are running fine when only scenarios 1, 2 and 3 are in place. However, when I insert the script of the `ElseIf` statement in scenario 4, something goes wrong. Although scenarios 1 and 2 keep on working, whenever I search for a country on which I know there are entries for "Category" and "Subcategory", the script prompts scenario 4 as if there were no matches for that "Country", "Category" and "Subcategory".

I am not sure what I might be doing wrong or what the problem is with my `ElseIf` statement.

---

### Whole Code

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

Dim country As String 'Search query category user-inputted
Dim Category As String 'Search query category user-inputted
Dim Subcategory As String 'Search query category user-inputted
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim LastRowForTable As Long 'Last filled row in Results table
Dim i As Integer 'row counter
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Database")

'Erase any entries from the Results sheet
Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J200000").ClearContents

'Define the user-inputed variables
country = Sheets("Results").Range("D5").Value
Category = Sheets("Results").Range("D6").Value
Subcategory = Sheets("Results").Range("D7").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Database").Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row

'If statement for search    
With Worksheets("Database")
    Set c = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=country, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    Else
        MsgBox "Unfortunately, the database does not have any sources for information in " & country & ". Please search for sources in relating to another country."
        Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'If the country field is left empty, there is no need to even run a search
If country = "" Then
    Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J200000").Clear
    MsgBox "You must select a country in order to search the database. Please do so in the drop-down list provided."
    Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
    Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
    Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 2 To finalrow

    'If the country field is filled in and there results from the search made
    If Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = country And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 3) = Category Or Category = "") And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 4) = Subcategory Or Subcategory = "") Then

        'Copy the headers of the "Database" sheet
        With Sheets("Database")
            .Range("A1:I1").Copy
        End With
        Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J10").PasteSpecial

        'Copy the rows of the table that match the search query
        With Sheets("Database")
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 9)).Copy
        End With
        Sheets("Results").Range("B20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

    ElseIf Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = country And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 3) <> Category) Then

        Dim question As Integer
        question = MsgBox("Unfortunately, the Database has no sources regarding " & Category & " in " & country & ". Would you perhaps want to broaden your search and see all sources regarding " & country & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")
        Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents

        MsgBox question
        If question = vbYes Then
            Close
            Call SearchButton_Click
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
            Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
            Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If

Next i

'Hides search form
Me.Hide

'Toggle Results sheet
Sheets("Results").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: As a quick sidenote - you might want to change `finalRow` and `i` to a `Long` instead of an `Integer`. That tends to be a run-time error waiting to happen.

Comment: When you say "something goes wrong" do you mean it's throwing an error or just not functioning as expected?

Comment: There is no error. Just this: although scenarios 1 and 2 keep on working, whenever I search for a country on which I know there are entries for "Category" and "Subcategory", the script prompts scenario 4 as if there were no matches for that "Country", "Category" and "Subcategory". Thank you.

Comment: Another quick side note - you are copying your column headers into the results sheet inside the iteration (under your IF statement in scenario 3). If you are finding multiple rows that meet your criteria it might slow your code down somewhat as its only necessary to do once. Just a thought :)

Comment: Good point! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

Dim country As String 'Search query category user-inputted
Dim Category As String 'Search query category user-inputted
Dim Subcategory As String 'Search query category user-inputted
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim LastRowForTable As Long 'Last filled row in Results table
Dim i As Integer 'row counter
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Database")

'Erase any entries from the Results sheet
Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J200000").ClearContents

'Define the user-inputed variables
country = Sheets("Results").Range("D5").Value
Category = Sheets("Results").Range("D6").Value
Subcategory = Sheets("Results").Range("D7").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Database").Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row

'If statement for search    
With Worksheets("Database")
    Set c = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=country, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    Else
        MsgBox "Unfortunately, the database does not have any sources for information in " & country & ". Please search for sources in relating to another country."
        Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
        Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'If the country field is left empty, there is no need to even run a search
If country = "" Then
    Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J200000").Clear
    MsgBox "You must select a country in order to search the database. Please do so in the drop-down list provided."
    Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
    Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
    Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 2 To finalrow

    'If the country field is filled in and there results from the search made
    If Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = country And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 3) = Category Or Category = "") And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 4) = Subcategory Or Subcategory = "") Then

        'Copy the headers of the "Database" sheet
        With Sheets("Database")
            .Range("A1:I1").Copy
        End With
        Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J10").PasteSpecial

        'Copy the rows of the table that match the search query
        With Sheets("Database")
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 9)).Copy
        End With
        Sheets("Results").Range("B20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

    ElseIf Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = country And _
        (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 3) <> Category) Then

        Dim question As Integer
        question = MsgBox("Unfortunately, the Database has no sources regarding " & Category & " in " & country & ". Would you perhaps want to broaden your search and see all sources regarding " & country & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")

        MsgBox question
        If question = vbYes Then
            Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
            Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
            Category = Sheets("Results").Range("D6").Value
            Subcategory = Sheets("Results").Range("D7").Value
            If Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 1) = country And _
                (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 3) = Category Or Category = "") And _
                (Sheets("Database").Cells(i, 4) = Subcategory Or Subcategory = "") Then

                'Copy the headers of the "Database" sheet
                    With Sheets("Database")
                        .Range("A1:I1").Copy
                    End With
                    Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J10").PasteSpecial

                        'Copy the rows of the "Database" that match the search query
                    With Sheets("Database")
                        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 9)).Copy
                    End With
                    Sheets("Results").Range("B20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
        Else
            Sheets("Results").Range("D5").ClearContents
            Sheets("Results").Range("D6").ClearContents
            Sheets("Results").Range("D7").ClearContents
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If

Next i

'Hides search form
Me.Hide

'Toggle Results sheet
Sheets("Results").Activate

End Sub
```

Ok what i did:

Stopped the end of sub and recalling.

Stuck scenario 3 in the if msgbox=yes clause. This of course requires that we reset category and subcategory to blank, which I also did.

Comment: Still does not work. Scenarios 1,2 and 3 started working when I changed what you suggested and scenario 4 just returns the "Results" sheet blank instead of the `MsgBox`.

Comment: Yes, scenario 3 accounts for the event that "Category" and "Subcategory" are blank.

Comment: Well if three already accounts for it, why are you spinning your wheels?

Comment: Because in scenario 4 "Category" and "Subcategory" are not left blank. Rather, they are filled in by the user but the database just does not have any matches for the combination of that specific "Country" and "Category" and/or "Subcategory".

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I am understanding. Where should I put the first bit of code?

Comment: underneath the first FIND() method.

Comment: Still the same. Scenario 4 returns a blank "Results" sheet. but if I have understood correctly, in your suggestion, the script looks for a "Category" independently of the "Country", i.e., it does not look for the "Category" only in the country searched but in the total range of categories. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128841/discussion-between-doug-coats-and-franciscofcosta).